# Nnls problem with certain number of zeros as constraints

Tags: optimization, constraints, least-squares

I am doing an optimization problem To minimise square difference of Ax and b.

A is a matrix of m*n where x is non negative n vector. I would like to add a constraint that p out of n elements in vector x is zero.

How should I formulate the condition? It sounds to have nCp set of nnls optimization problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A standard formulation for this is to add a **cardinality constraint**:

```
 min ||Ax-b||^2
 x[i] ≤ δ[i]*U
 sum(i,δ[i]) = n-p
 δ[i] ∈ {0,1}
 x[i] ∈ [0,U]
```

This is an MIQP (Mixed-Integer Quadratic Programming) model. `U` is an upperbound on `x[i]` (should be not too large). `δ[i]` is a **binary decision variable** with meaning:

```
δ[i] = 1:  variable x[i] is allowed to vary between 0 and U
δ[i] = 0:  variable x[i] must be zero
```

Somewhat redundantly: the model computes both `x` and `δ`. (That is what "variable" means.)

MIQP solvers are readily available.

Comment: Thanks but this will make the optimization target becomes ||Ax*δ-b||^2 instead, not sure if there is proper algorithm to find out the solution.

Comment: @HiuleongNg Your notation is not correct (matrix multiplication vs element-wise multiplication). Besides, you still don't have a sparse x at the end. Also. you have a more complex MINLP model. Your model is just not a good idea IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, I think my notation was not precise enough and I was trying to say element wise multiplication. It because I was trying to link miqp to my problem which is going to minimise Ax - b but part of elements in x are zero. I was thinking whether δ[i] is an additional variable , thx

Comment: My suggested MIQP is a standard way of doing this. You can find this easily in the literature. It is related to cardinality-constrained portfolio models.

Comment: Thanks! I am sorry that i didnt state the problem clearly. For example, n = 3 and p = 2. So vector x would have 3 elements, x1, x2 and x3. And its possible that one of them is zero and the remaining two would be just a positive number. But it seems that if I use MIQP then i need to specify which variable (x1, x2 or x3) to be zero and others will be real number. Then it becomes 3 subset NNLS problem (x1 = 0, x2 = 0 or x3 = 0). Not sure if single MIQP can automatically find the best combination (like x2 = 0 and x1 = 0.7 and x3 = 1.8)

Comment: Is δ[i] one of those testing variables ? as its either 0 or 1 but it seems not appeared in the objective function

Comment: My problem is that if all elements are equal to 1, then Ax = b. But i wanna find a combination of xi such that only part of xi are non zero. So if it doesnt consider δ[i] in objective function then it will always find the solution of all 1 for all elements of x

Comment: *But it seems that if I use MIQP then i need to specify which variable (x1, x2 or x3) to be zero and others will be real number.*  Sorry, this is just not true. The δ variables are endogenous: they are determined by the model. I suggest to talk to your teacher to clear up the math.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Would you mind suggesting me some textbooks or lecture notes for MIQP problem? Thanks!